# How to determine the number of critical points a polynomial scalar field has?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, scalar-fields, real-algebraic-geometry

Consider the function

$$f(x,y) = x^3 + 3y - y^3 - 3x$$

How would I be able to determine the number of critical points $f(x,y)$ has?

I know critical points will exist if $\nabla f(x,y) = 0$ or $f_x(x,y) $ and/or $ f_y(x,y)$ don't exist. But if I don't care about the particular values of the critical points, is there just a way to determine the number of critical points?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know a general method apart of solving a counting.

Comment: Even for polynomials in one dimension, the number of critical points is not a trivial problem. In two dimensions, with more possible functions, to my knowledge there is no simple method available.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2),

```
Macaulay2, version 1.16
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, InverseSystems,
               LLLBases, MinimalPrimes, PrimaryDecomposition, ReesAlgebra,
               TangentCone, Truncations

i1 : R = QQ[x,y]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : I = ideal(3*x^2 - 3, 3 - 3*y^2)

              2          2
o2 = ideal (3x  - 3, - 3y  + 3)

o2 : Ideal of R

i3 : dim I

o3 = 0

i4 : degree I

o4 = 4
```

Hence, there are $4$ critical points. It's easy to conclude that these $4$ points are $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$.

---

<sub>Bernd Sturmfels, [Ideals, Varieties and Macaulay 2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/Book/ComputationsBook/chapters/varieties/chapter-wrapper.pdf) [PDF]</sub>